# Keep company name in app logo differ to app name in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I want to add my company name in application logo which is different than application name.

i.e. My company name is "ABC" and application name is "XYZ". We need to upload app logo(app icon) which is 1024*1024 in max size icon. This app icon has big letters "ABC" only which is different than application name "XYZ".

Please let me know if Apple may reject this app or not?

Also, if Apple may reject this then what is the best solution to promote my company name on AppStore?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't see why it would be a problem. Look on app store at FIFA game, that has EA Sports logo on the app icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead buddy.I think they wouldn't have any issue with this.For more details you can refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#metadata)

Comment: Thank you so much... I was scared with the rejection process of Apple as it may take more 14days.... Your answer is really helpful to me...

Answer (score 3):

There should not be any issue in keeping company name in app logo different to app name in ios

Answer (score -2):

Yes You can do It But

Your `Apps` Name And Company name same use but your Company/apps name never use in `AppStore` and  your apps name was not inlegel only Two condition

Like `Facebook`,`OlX`, `amazon` All Are Company  And `Apps` available on `app store`

More INfo https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#metadata

Comment: iF you are agree then Plz Accept my ans